# How would I make this test pass?

Tags: java

How would i make the constructor store its parameter into the instance variable sentence? do i need to use the new operator?

```
public class SentenceCounter
{
public String sentence;

    public SentenceCounter(String sentence)
    {

    }

    public Object getSentence()
    {

        return sentence;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class TestSentenceCounter {

        private static final String SENTENCE1 =
                "This is my sentence.";
        private static final String SENTENCE2 =
                "These words make another sentence that is longer";
        private SentenceCounter sc1;
        private SentenceCounter sc2;

        /**
         * Create two instance variable is correct
         */
        @Before
        public void setup()
        {
         sc1 = new SentenceCounter(SENTENCE1);
         sc2 = new SentenceCounter(SENTENCE2);
        }
        /** 
         * Make sure the instance variable is correct 
         */

    @Test
    public void testConstructor()
    {
        assertEquals(SENTENCE1, sc1.getSentence());
        assertEquals(SENTENCE2, sc2.getSentence());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would i make the constructor store its parameter into the instance
>   variable sentence?

```
public class SentenceCounter
{
public String sentence;

    public SentenceCounter(String sentence)
    {
        this.sentence = sentence; // This is how
    }

    public Object getSentence()
    {

        return sentence;
    }

}
```

In your code, you don't use constructor parameter to initialize `sentence` variable.

With `this.sentence = sentence` statement, the problem is fixed. Therefore your tests will pass. Problem was not in the tests, was in `SentenceCounter` class constructor.

Comment: Could you explain why that makes the test pass?

Comment: I did edit my answer, sc1.getSentence() equals SENTENCE1 after this fix, so your test will pass.

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor you either will rename the argument variable name or use this.variable.

```
public SentenceCounter(String sentence) {
    this.sentence = sentence;
}

public SentenceCounter(String s) {
    sentence = s;
}
```